# Fixed navigation bar is overlapped by Image Slider when scrolling

Tags: html, css, image, navigation, slider

I currently have a web page with a fixed navigation bar at the top. Everything works fine, except an image slider I have in the content of the website overlaps the fixed navigation bar when scrolling down, contrary to the rest of the site, which underlaps the bar when scrolling. I have the position: relative style attached to the slider & position:fixed to the navigation bar. I also tried adding z-index:1; to the nav and z-index:2 to the slider, which someone recommended in another post - with no luck.

I appreciate the help!

here is the URL to my problem: http://www.kyniko.com/golf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the z-index of the navigation bar to be bigger than the z-index on the image slider. I went to your site, scrolled down until the image was on top of the nav bar, changed the z-index on the nav bar to 99 and the image went under it.